# How do i remove the backgroundcolor in a <th> tag in all IE browsers when using background images?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style my table-head so it has rounded corners with images like this:

```
<tr style="background: url(middleimage.gif) repeat-x;">
    <th style="background: url(leftimage.gif) no-repeat;">
        title
    </th>
    <th>
        title
    </th>
    <th style="background: url(rightimage.gif) no-repeat;">
        title
    </th>
</tr>
```

in firefox this works fine, but in ie it fills out the first and last th-tag with a white background color and not showing the background-image in the tr-tag.

Example:

[image]

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
style="background: transparent url(yourimage.xyz) no-repeat;"
```

Comment: an online example would be the best.